# Streching Layout & Even Distribution of Project Steps: Visualisation of a Custom Progress Bar (CSS/HTML)

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-selectors, progress-bar

I have been working on a custom progress bar that shows three kinds of steps: *done*, *busy* and *todo* steps.  The basic html ul li is based on flexbox, where items can be added or taken out, without breaking the integrity of the layout.

[image]

I would like the steps to extend left and right, but cannot achieve this without breaking the width of the items.
All steps should be equal in width.
The current design works (and must remain working) with one, two, three, four or five steps.

I want the entire progress bar to stretch porportionally and fill the yellow area completely.

The final intended result should look something like this:

[image]

Here, the first and last bullet-tets should touch the ends of the yellow background, an all bullets should be centered above the text words.

There can be two variations: 1) The bullets having equali distance to one another. 2) The bullets spacing denepnding on the length of the text words. Both are fine, whichever containst the least amount of code.

In summary, the answered soludion should:

- Get rid of the unused yellow space left and right surrounding the progress bar
- While evenly distributing all bullets and their texts
- All bullets should remain centered above the texts
- Remain working when two, three, four and five li items populate the unordered list.

### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/9s48naw0/

```css
body{
  background: lightblue;
  width: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
a{text-decoration: none}

.progress {
    display: flex;
    background: yellow;
    width: auto;
}

.progress>li {
    flex: 1;
}

.progress>li, .progress>li a{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: lightgrey;
    display: block;
}

.progress>li .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto .5em;
}

.progress>li .circle:after,
.progress>li .circle:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    content: '';
    background: lightgrey;
}


.progress>li :before {left: 0}
.progress>li :after {right: 0}

.progress>li:first-child .circle:after,
.progress>li:first-child .circle:before {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%
}

.progress>li:last-child .circle:after,
.progress>li:last-child .circle:before {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%
}

.progress>li.done .circle,
.progress>li.done .circle:after,
.progress>li.done .circle:before {background: green}
.progress>li.done,
.progress>li.done a{color: green}

.progress>li.busy .circle,
.progress>li.busy .circle:after,
.progress>li.busy .circle:before {background: violet}
.progress>li.busy,
.progress>li.busy a{color: violet}
```

```html
<ul class="progress">


  <li class="done">
    <a href="#" title="More about the First Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step1</a>
  </li>


  <li class="done">
    <a href="#" title="Afterwards the Second Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step2</a>
  </li>


  <li class="busy">
    <a href="#" title="This about the current active Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step3</a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Future Next Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step4</a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="#" title="And the Final Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step5</a>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sam, Please check the result and let me know your opinion. I hope it would be helpful for you ~

```css
body {
            background: lightblue;
            width: auto;
            padding: 50px;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none
        }

        .progress {
            display: flex;
            background: yellow;
            width: auto;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .progress>li {
            flex: 2;
        }

        .progress>li:first-child,
        .progress>li:last-child {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .progress>li:first-child a {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .progress>li:last-child a {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .progress>li,
        .progress>li a {
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            position: relative;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            color: lightgrey;
            display: block;
        }

        .progress>li .circle {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            background: lightgrey;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto .5em;
        }

        .progress>li:first-child .circle {
            margin-left: 7px;
        }

        .progress>li:last-child .circle {
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .progress>li .circle:after,
        .progress>li .circle:before {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 4px;
            content: '';
            background: lightgrey;
        }

        .progress>li :before {
            left: 0
        }

        .progress>li :after {
            right: 0
        }

        .progress>li:first-child .circle:after,
        .progress>li:first-child .circle:before {
            width: 50%;
        }

        .progress>li:last-child .circle:after,
        .progress>li:last-child .circle:before {
            width: 50%;
        }

        .progress>li:first-child .circle::before {
            width: calc(50% - 10px);
            left: 10px;
        }
        .progress>li:last-child .circle::after {
            width: calc(50% - 10px);
            right: 10px;
        }

        .progress>li.done .circle,
        .progress>li.done .circle:after,
        .progress>li.done .circle:before {
            background: green
        }

        .progress>li.done,
        .progress>li.done a {
            color: green
        }

        .progress>li.busy .circle,
        .progress>li.busy .circle:after,
        .progress>li.busy .circle:before {
            background: violet
        }

        .progress>li.busy,
        .progress>li.busy a {
            color: violet
        }
```

```html
<ul class="progress">


  <li class="done">
    <a href="#" title="More about the First Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step1</a>
  </li>


  <li class="done">
    <a href="#" title="Afterwards the Second Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step2</a>
  </li>


  <li class="busy">
    <a href="#" title="This about the current active Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step3</a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Future Next Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step4</a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="#" title="And the Final Step">
      <span class="circle"></span>
    Step5</a>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: @sam, edited the dynamic width, however for the text align, we need to change the structure of the html.
I think that it would be great for current text align as a frontend dev experience.

Comment: Brilliant elaboration using calc(). From my initial testing it seems to work nicely! If I understand correctly, you would like to change the structure of the HTML that could benefit the design? You are welcome, go ahead and update your snippet.

Comment: Thanks again Alex for your awesome contribution. Both your solution and that of Witney O. work 100% flawlessly! It was very very difficult to choose whom to award! The differences were very slight. Her better explanation and elaboration earned her the award but you were the first to answer so you I'm accepting your answer!

Answer (score 1):

My idea starts like this:
Since there are two halves of each li item and the first and last items are halves, the best ratio is `1:2:2:2:1`. This means each li item will be twice of the first and last items. Hence `flex:1` for li and `flex:0.5` for the first and last.

```
.progress>li { 
flex: 1; 
} 
.progress>li:last-child{
 flex:0.5;
 } 
.progress>li:first-child { 
flex:0.5; 
}
```

Then send the content in the first and last circles to the edges instead of the center.

```
.progress>li:last-child, 
.progress>li:last-child a
{ text-align: right; } 

.progress>li:first-child, 
.progress>li:first-child a
{ text-align: left; }
```

The left and right margin on all li items was set to `margin: 0 auto .5em;`.

Change the margins for the pseudo-elements in the first and last circles.

```
.progress>li:first-child .circle:after, 
.progress>li:first-child .circle:before { 
width: 50%; 
margin: 0 auto 0 0.5em; 
} 
.progress>li:last-child .circle:after, 
.progress>li:last-child .circle:before { 
width: 50%; 
margin: 0 0.5em 0 auto; 
}
```

The complete CSS is:

```
body{
  background: lightblue;
  width: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
a{text-decoration: none}

.progress {
    display: flex;
    background: yellow;
    width: auto;
  padding:0;
}

.progress>li {
    flex: 1;
}
.progress>li:last-child{
  flex:0.5;
}
.progress>li:first-child {
  flex:0.5;
}

.progress>li, .progress>li a{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: lightgrey;
    display: block;
}

.progress>li:last-child, .progress>li:last-child a{
  text-align: right;
  }
.progress>li:first-child, .progress>li:first-child a{
  text-align: left;
  }

.progress>li .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto .5em;
}

.progress>li .circle:after,
.progress>li .circle:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    content: '';
    background: lightgrey;
}


.progress>li :before {left: 0}
.progress>li :after {right: 0}

.progress>li:first-child .circle:after,
.progress>li:first-child .circle:before {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 0.5em;
}

.progress>li:last-child .circle:after,
.progress>li:last-child .circle:before {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 auto;
}

.progress>li.done .circle,
.progress>li.done .circle:after,
.progress>li.done .circle:before {background: green}
.progress>li.done,
.progress>li.done a{color: green}

.progress>li.busy .circle,
.progress>li.busy .circle:after,
.progress>li.busy .circle:before {background: violet}
.progress>li.busy,
.progress>li.busy a{color: violet}

.progress>li:last-child .circle{
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em auto;
}
.progress>li:first-child .circle{
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

The bullets are equidistant. Check the result on [this pen](https://codepen.io/somtoChukwun/pen/MWQBLLG).

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Comment: Fixed it. It was the margin on the circle spans.

Comment: Awesome Flexbox solution! If you wish you can combine the old & new CSS into one code block in your answer and clean up duplicate selectors. (No need to keep old code separate from your answer). Feel free to combine and clean up your beautiful answer! 
Less code means more elegant solution. Also feel free to write in a few sentences what you did in your answer, as suggested by Ethan.

Comment: Added more details, Ethan. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Whitney O. Welcome to Stack Overflow, as a small token of my esteem I'm awaring you the bonus because your code was the shortest and very elegant. Thanks!

Comment: You don't say! Thanks, Sam. Talk about a warm welcome. I'm grinning! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, rebuilded. I used **grid** instead of **flexbox** to remove unnecessary DOM elements and simplify html and css. Also, in your solution, links don't have gaps. For example, if user clicks in the middle beetwen two steps, what should happents? In that case the best way to keep gaps without interaction.
Another strange approach, **busy** track (line) in the middle? Look more familiar, if only dot has status **busy** or  dot and the whole track.

```html
<section class="progress">
  <a href="#" class="step done" title="More about the First Step"> Step1</a>
  <a href="#" class="step done" title="Afterwards the Second Step"> Step2</a>
  <a href="#" class="step busy" title="This about the current active Step"> Step3</a>
  <a href="#" class="step" title="Future Next Step"> Step4</a>
  <a href="#" class="step" title="And the Final Step"> Step5</a>
</section>
```

##### 5 steps

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.progress {
  --step-width: 1.5rem;
  --outside-margin: 1.5rem;
  --track-number: 4;
  --disable-color: lightgrey;
  --busy-color: violet;
  --done-color: green;

  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: calc(var(--step-width) * 2);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background: yellow;
  width: auto;
  margin-inline: var(--outside-margin);
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--disable-color);
}
.step:not(:first-child):after {
  content: '';
  /* Take entire width and subtracting right, left margin,
  then divide into four tracks and subtract half of one column. */
  width: calc((100vw - var(--outside-margin) * 2) / var(--track-number) - (var(--step-width) / 2));
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  background: var(--disable-color);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.step::before {
  content: '';
  width: var(--step-width);
  height: var(--step-width);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  background: var(--disable-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.done {
  color: var(--done-color);
}
.busy {
  color: var(--busy-color);
}
.step.done::after,
.step.done::before {
  background: var(--done-color);
}
.step.busy::after,
.step.busy::before {
  background: var(--busy-color);
}
```

```html
<section class="progress">
  <a href="#" class="step done" title="More about the First Step"> Step1</a>
  <a href="#" class="step done" title="Afterwards the Second Step"> Step2</a>
  <a href="#" class="step busy" title="This about the current active Step"> Step3</a>
  <a href="#" class="step" title="Future Next Step"> Step4</a>
  <a href="#" class="step" title="And the Final Step"> Step5</a>
</section>
```

##### 4 steps

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.progress {
  --step-width: 1.5rem;
  --outside-margin: 1.5rem;
  --track-number: 3;
  --disable-color: lightgrey;
  --busy-color: violet;
  --done-color: green;

  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: calc(var(--step-width) * 2);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background: yellow;
  width: auto;
  margin-inline: var(--outside-margin);
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--disable-color);
}
.step:not(:first-child):after {
  content: '';
  /* Take entire width and subtracting right, left margin,
  then divide into four tracks and subtract half of one column. */
  width: calc((100vw - var(--outside-margin) * 2) / var(--track-number) - (var(--step-width) / 2));
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  background: var(--disable-color);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.step::before {
  content: '';
  width: var(--step-width);
  height: var(--step-width);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  background: var(--disable-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.done {
  color: var(--done-color);
}
.busy {
  color: var(--busy-color);
}
.step.done::after,
.step.done::before {
  background: var(--done-color);
}
.step.busy::after,
.step.busy::before {
  background: var(--busy-color);
}
```

```html
<section class="progress">
  <a href="#" class="step done" title="More about the First Step"> Step1</a>
  <a href="#" class="step done" title="Afterwards the Second Step"> Step2</a>
  <a href="#" class="step busy" title="This about the current active Step"> Step3</a>
  <a href="#" class="step" title="Future Next Step"> Step4</a>
  <!-- <a href="#" class="step" title="And the Final Step"> Step5</a> -->
</section>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your impressive answer! Unfortunately the last bullet in the quetsion is not adressed! (The layout breaks when there is less than five `<li>` steps). I awarded the new person who just joined Stack Overflow because her solution does address the last bullet: her layout does not break when there is less than five `<li>` steps.

Comment: The layout breaks, because i created a calculation for five steps. So, 5 steps have four tracks, if you need 4 steps, **process** class has variable **--track-number** and  only need to change amount tracks from 4 to 3.